# MYSQL 'replace into' statement goes wrong

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_cpxs |
+----------------+
| course         |
| score          |
| students       |
| teach          |
+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO  课程表 SELECT * FROM course;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'cpxs.课程表' doesn't exist
mysql> SELECT*FROM 课程表;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'cpxs.课程表' doesn't exist
mysql> INSERT INTO 课程表 SELECT*FROM course;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'cpxs.课程表' doesn't exist
```

i tried to add a space bar in INSERT INTO 课程表 SELECT*FROM course;
but it's still not working

Comment: do you have `课程表` table?

Comment: nope and my textbook tell me i can just import the data from course into '课程表'

Comment: errmm, its better to stick with ASCII for table and database names, like `class_schedule` for instance.

Comment: You can use international characters (UTF-8) for table names (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) but regardless of the name of the table, you must create that table before you can insert into it. Your textbook should make that clear, but if it didn't, then we're telling you now.

Comment: You can also use `CREATE TABLE 课程表 AS SELECT * FROM course;` which counts as creating the new table and also filling it with the result of that SELECT query. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: Double check what database engine your textbook is teaching. Every database vendor implements a sometimes vastly different SQL dialect.